# How to avoid insert empty record in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In my script i can create a new collection in mongodb but default one empty record is inserting so how to avoid that.

model.js:

```
 /* model.js */
 'use strict';

 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;


 function dynamicModel(suffix) {
   var addressSchema = new Schema({

    product_name: {
        type: String
    }

   }); 
   return mongoose.model(suffix, addressSchema); 
  } 
  module.exports = dynamicModel;
```

data.controller.js:

```
      var NewModel = require(path.resolve('./models/model.js'))(collectionName);
      NewModel.create({ category: 1, title: 'Minion' }, function(err, doc) {

      });
```

after created new collection I am seeing like this:

```
  _id:ObjectId("5eceb362d538901accc0fefe");
  __v:0
```

Comment: `category` and `title` attributes are not available in your `Schema`, that's why it's creating a collection with only `_id` and `__v`.

Comment: @Vishnu: So can i remove category and title?

Comment: The `strict` option is by default enabled in `Schema`. If you need to add extra fields that are not specified in Schema you can set the `strict` option to `false`. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define these attributes in your model.

```
 /* model.js */
 'use strict';

 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;


 function dynamicModel(suffix) {
   var addressSchema = new Schema({

    product_name: {
        type: String,
    },
    category: {
       type: Number,
    },
    title: {
       type: String,
    }

   }); 
   return mongoose.model(suffix, addressSchema); 
  } 
  module.exports = dynamicModel;
```